# I am receiving an int from 1-7 for the day of the week, and I need to compare it to 7 weekday columns?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, datetime, graphql, schema

I am writing a function in which one of the parameters is and INT weekday for the current day. If the day is Sunday, it will be 1, and a Monday will be a 2, etc.

Inside of my database, there is a table for each item on an order sheet. They have many columns and 7 of them are isSunday, isMonday, isTuesday, etc. They have a boolean value for if the item is buyable on that given day.

So I need to take that INT of 1 or whatever and figure out what day of the week that is. Then compare it to the isSunday or watever column to see if the value is true. If it is, it will return the entire row for that item. If the value is 0 for that given day, it will not return that item.

PS another parameter I am getting is the time of day. This figures out if the time is between the starttime and endtime because some items are only sold in the morning like breakfast.

I was thinking that instead of getting 2 different parameters for INT weekday and TIME timeofday, i just got one large calendar value that had the date and time in it. And then split it up to compare it to the columns, but I dont know if that is making it too complex.

this is the schema

```
getLocationLiveMenu(p_locationID: Int!, p_timeofday: time, p_dayofweek: int): [LocationMenu]
```

[LocationMenu]

it would be stored here. an array within an array.

```
type LocationMenu {
    locationID: Int
    menucategoryID: Int
    name: String
    menuItems: [LocationMenuItem]
}

type LocationMenuItem {
    locationMenuItemID: Int
    locationID: Int
    name: String
    description: String
    price: Float
    photo: String
}
```

this livemenuget needs to be one function. 2 separate is not acceptable

this is calling on a stored procedure in the sql server which i also have to create

```
SELECT  s.startTime, s.endTime, s.description, s.locationID, s.onSunday, s.onMonday, s.onTuesday, s.onWednesday, s.onThursday, s.onFriday, s.onSaturday, l.locationMenuItemID, l.menuCategoryID, l.name, l.description, l.price, l.photo, l.isAllDay, l.scheduleID
  FROM company.menuschedules s left join company.locationmenuitem l on l.locationID = s.locationID where p_locationID = l.locationID and p_currentTime BETWEEN s.startTime AND s.endTime 
  and if(
        p_weekday = 1
        then check isMonday
        or if p_weekday = 2
        then check isTuesday
        ...
        ...

        )

       if booleanvalue = true then return locationmenuitem
;
```

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema; a database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: what  part should i redesign? could you elaborate more please, I am overwhelmed by the maintenance.

Comment: Without seeing your schema, it's hard to say.

Comment: Clarifying questions: What database are you using? Specifically, do you have SQL queries available to you. Additionally, the time component greatly complicates the solution and may require a totally different solution. You can run BETWEEN queries in most SQL languages an manufacture dates within the query but a a great performance cost typically.

Comment: I added the schema that is providing parameters and making an array within an array to store the items and item info  for each item.  this is a communication between appsync and my sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a column for each day of the week, consider either:

a) storing a bitwise value for weekdays, whereby 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, 4 = Tuesday, and 128 = Every day.

or

b) storing the week days in a separate table, with a separate row for each location/weekday pairing.